# 100% width div with box shadow ovelaps parent div

Tags: css-float, css, fluid-layout

I have a centered container div that has currently 3 other divs inside. They all have box shadows (about 5px margin is added as a result).

The issue I am having is that the first div(upcoming) is 100% width and is either cut off on the right hand side (`overflow: hidden` is set). or it overflows it's containing div a little. This would be ok but the other 2 divs underneath are floated to be side by side and so do not overflow even a little (recent div moves under latest if size is set to more than space available).

Padding doesn't help. Is there any solution other than setting width to something like 98%?

Here's the css I am using:

```
.mainSection{
    width:1020px;
    margin:70px auto 0px auto;
}

.widget{
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px #CCC;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px #CCC;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px #CCC;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    margin:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* 3 child divs */

.widget.upcoming{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:380px;
}

.widget.recent{
    float:right;
    width:260px;
    height:auto;
}

.widget.latest{
    float:left;
    width:740px;
    height:460px;
}

<section class="mainSection">
    <article class="widget upcoming">
        <header>
            <h3>Upcoming</h3>
        </header>
    </article>
    <article class="widget news">
        <article>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </article>
    </article>
    <article class="widget latest">
        <header>
            <h3>Latest</h3>
        </header>
    </article>
    <aside class="widget recent">
        <header>
            <h3>Recent</h3>
        </header>
    </aside>    
</section>
```

Comment: Yes please html, I'm trying to help and if more info would be awesome http://jsbin.com/uharax/1/

Comment: In the jsbin example you can see the issue (set px height on .recent for clarity). the .upcoming div is longer than the divs below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we changed Change

```
.widget.upcoming{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   height:380px;
}
```

to

```
 .widget.upcoming{
    height:380px;
 }
```

I think it should work

http://jsbin.com/uharax/1

Comment: Seems to work, but will it scale to 100% all the time? I mean now it scales only because the text by default is 100%. What if I only have fixed width/height divs inside and no text?

Comment: Actually, it seems to work just fine because elements inside have auto margin.

Comment: That's awesome , really happy it works for you. Just I'm playing with it, http://jsbin.com/uharax/5/ . If you want to set the width to 100% and float it to left, just remove the margin: 4px; form .widget because it increase the size around the element. and we can use box-sizing too so the border will be inside the element width. Also added some boxes inside. check the example. Have a great day :)

Comment: Margin is required or the shadow is cut off or overlaps other shadows. I might just go with isotope jquery plugin for this...